# How to return Mongo referenced documents when we query ElasticSearch with {hydrate:true}?

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I have query like this:

```
Book.search(esQuery, {
  hydrate: true
}, function(err, res) {
  if (res) {
    return cb(null, res.hits.hits);
  } else {
    return cb 'error',null
  }
});
```

I have a referenced document in the Book document. 
Is it possible load Mongo referenced in res.hits.hits?